# Why do Swift playgrounds begin with "//:"?

Tags: swift, xcode, formatting, format, comments

Most Swift documentation is provided in the form `///`. What is the meaning of `//:` e.g. in the context `//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play` the default header string in Xcode Swift playground documents?

Comment: In this case it could be just `//`. Is there any significance to the `:` suffix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Single Line Comment](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/SingleLineComment.html) in the Markup Formatting Reference:

> Use two forward slash (/) characters followed by a colon (:) for a single line of markup for a playground.

You'll see the effect if you select "Editor -> Show Rendered Markup":

[image]